# How can I specify an integer index in sympy?

Tags: python, sympy

I was trying to verify the Euler's formula by:

```py
import sympy
n = sympy.Symbol('n', integer=True)
print(sympy.exp(- sympy.I * n * sympy.pi))
```

The result is `exp(-I*pi*n)` instead of `(-1)**n`.

What should I do to get the right answer?

Answer (score 2):

use

```
print((sympy.exp(- sympy.I * n * sympy.pi)).simplify())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `simplify` for that. Source: [simplify](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/simplification.html#simplify)

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> n = symbols('n', integer=True)
>>> simplify(exp(-I*n*pi))
(-1)**n
```